I want to put the chapter name on top of a titlerule
I would like to put the title name on top of the 2 rules, such as the chapter number.

Here's a MWE, i've put everything just to make sure
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{siunitx, tikz, tcolorbox, setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor, color, tabularray, longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb, graphicx, lipsum, mathtools}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=4pt]{caption}

\usepackage[capbesideposition={center, right}]{floatrow}
\usepackage{wrapfig, subfigure, subcaption, textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, fncychap, lastpage, etoolbox, titlesec, bm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref,csquotes}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[OR]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
      \fancyhf{} 
      \setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
      \fancyhead[EL]{\footnotesize\sffamily\nouppercase\leftmark}
      \fancyhead[OR]{\footnotesize\sffamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
      \fancyfoot[EL]{\thepage}
      \fancyfoot[OR]{\thepage}
      \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ ##1}{}}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
      \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    }

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
      {\normalfont\Huge\sffamily}
    {\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\hspace{10pt}\thechapter}
      {20pt}
      {\titlerule\vspace{2pt}\titlerule \\[10pt]\Huge\bfseries}


\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-75pt}{10pt}
    
\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}


Off-topic, but this example is not minimal. It seems like a titlesec problem, so all other packages are unnecessary.

You could try it like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}
  {.5em}
  {}
  [\vspace{6pt}\titlerule\vspace{2pt}\titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-75pt}
  {10pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduzione}
Questo è un esempio di testo per l'introduzione.

\end{document}

Here's how it looks like:

